# Reversing an input string in Assembly

Tags: string, assembly, dos, x86-16

I have this assembly code that reverses a string that I input. It only accepts maximum 20 characters. My problem is that when I hit enter to see the output there is an extra character at the end of the reversed string.
Please help me understand why that does occur and how I can remove that in the output.
We're required to only use function 09H int 21h to display the string and function 0Ah int 21h to input the string. We're using TASM.
Your help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data 
    MSG DB "Input String(max 20 chars): ", 10, 13, "$"
    Sentence1 DB 21,?,21 dup("$")  
    str2 dw 21 dup("$")
.code
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    ;Getting the string input
        mov ah,09h
        lea dx, MSG
        int 21h

        lea si,Sentence1
        mov ah,0ah
        mov dx,si
        int 21h

    ;Reverse String    
        mov cl,Sentence1
        add cl,1
        add si,2
    loop1:
        inc si
        cmp byte ptr[si],"$"
        jne loop1

        dec si
        lea di,str2
    loop2:
        mov al,byte ptr[si]
        mov byte ptr[di],al
        dec si
        inc di
        loop loop2

        ;Printing the reverse string    
            mov ah,09h
            lea dx,str2
            int 21h    

        mov ah, 4ch
        int 21h
end start
```

Comment: What extra character? Note that the read string will have a CR (ASCII 13) at the end. Also, there's no need for the loop that find the end of the read string; the number of characters read is returned through `[Sentence1+1]`.

Comment: extra character like heart,like the letter P facing backwards. Then I should just remove the loop1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> str2 dw 21 dup("$")
> ```

Normally this would be using the `db` directive.

---

> ```
> mov cl,Sentence1
> add cl,1
> ```

The reversal loop uses `CX` as its loop counter, but you don't set it correctly!
The 2nd byte of the "Sentence1" input structure, contains the value that you want in the `CX` register. You don't need to search for any terminating character. Moreover if you did, you'd rather have to look for ASCII code 13 (carriage return) instead of '$'.

```
mov cl, [si + 1]   ;Number of characters in the string
mov ch, 0          ;Make it a word because LOOP depends on CX (not just CL)
```

---

Setting up `SI` then becomes:

```
add si, 2          ;To the start of the string
add si, cx         ;To the position after the string
dec si             ;To the last character of the string
```

but shorter:

```
add si, cx
inc si
```

---

If ever the user didn't input any text, you will want to by-pass the reversal entirely! That's what the `jcxz` is for in next code:

```
 lea si, Sentence1
 mov ah, 0Ah
 mov dx, si
 int 21h

 ;Reverse String    
 mov cl, [si + 1]
 mov ch, 0
 add si, cx
 inc si
 lea di, str2

 jcxz EmptyString     ;By-pass the reversal entirely!

loop2:
 mov al, byte ptr[si]
 mov byte ptr[di], al
 dec si
 inc di
 loop loop2

EmptyString:
 ;Printing the reverse string (could be empty)
 mov ah, 09h
 lea dx, str2
 int 21h
```

Comment: OMG THANKS! IT FINALLY WORKS CORRECTLY!! I'll study what you've said, thanks!